# Separate 'free tagging' terms from normal taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

How to separate '**free tagging**' terms from normal taxonomy terms? By default Drupal outputs all terms despite of their vocabulary in one list, which isn’t great at all. On the output we want to get something like this:

`vocabulary:tag`.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are after here -- do you want to see all terms (regardless of taxonomy) in one list, but with the taxonomy name preceding the term name, or do you want separate lists by taxonomy?